# StreamingKit repeats song ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, audio-player

I have a trouble with playing queue of local (saved on device) song. I'm using this cocoapod - https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit. My first item in queue starts to play one more time after its finished. 
It has stopReason status NONE

```
    func audioPlayer(_ audioPlayer: STKAudioPlayer, didFinishPlayingQueueItemId queueItemId: NSObject, with stopReason: STKAudioPlayerStopReason, andProgress progress: Double, andDuration duration: Double) {

    if stopReason == .eof || stopReason == .pendingNext {
        checkNextTrack()
    }

    if stopReason == .none {
        print("NONE")
    }

    if stopReason == .error || stopReason == .userAction || stopReason == .disposed {
        stop()
        resetAudioPlayer()
    }
}
```

Other elements has statuses `.eof` or `.pendingNext` and this is correct behaviour. What should I do in that case? All remote urls are playing correctly.
Thnx!

**UPDATE:**
Queue creating

```
    internal func playWithQueue(queue: [Song], index: Int = 0) {
    var audioListNew = [AudioItem]()
    for (index, value) in queue.enumerated() {
        let audioItem = AudioItem(audioItem: value, audioIndex: index)
        audioListNew.append(audioItem)
    }

    guard index >= 0 && index < audioListNew.count else { return }
    newQueue(queue: audioListNew, index: index)
}


func newQueue(queue: [AudioItem], index: Int = 0) {
    self.queue = queue
    audioPlayer.clearQueue()

    if let currentSong = self.queue[index].audioItem {
        play(file: currentSong)

        for (songIndex, _) in queue.enumerated() {
            audioPlayer.queue( (queue[Int((index + songIndex) % queue.count)].audioItem?.songRealUrl)! )
        }

    }

    currentIndex = index
}
```

Comment: Hey. Is your first item playing one more time after it's finished for no reason or because you queued it to play after all the rest?

Comment: @tumtumtum For no reason. I can give you a part of my code where I creating a queue. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @tumtumtum Updated my question

Comment: @tumtumtum I mentioned that EVERY song from my queue ends with status .none, but player switches to next song. Is it normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and i solve it!
You need to do smth like that:

```
    -(void) audioPlayer:(STKAudioPlayer*)audioPlayer didFinishBufferingSourceWithQueueItemId:(NSObject*)queueItemId
{
    SampleQueueId* queueId = (SampleQueueId*)queueItemId;

    NSLog(@"Requeuing: %@", [queueId.url description]);

//    [self.audioPlayer queueDataSource:[STKAudioPlayer dataSourceFromURL:queueId.url] withQueueItemId:[[SampleQueueId alloc] initWithUrl:queueId.url andCount:queueId.count+1]];
}
```

**After that you need to write stop actions:**

```
    -(void) audioPlayer:(STKAudioPlayer*)audioPlayer didFinishPlayingQueueItemId:(NSObject*)queueItemId withReason:(STKAudioPlayerStopReason)stopReason andProgress:(double)progress andDuration:(double)duration
{
    SampleQueueId* queueId = (SampleQueueId*)queueItemId;
    NSLog(@"Finished: %@", [queueId.url description]);


    if(stopReason == STKAudioPlayerStopReasonEof)
        {
            if(self.isMainAudioPlay)
            {
                [self.mainAudioPlayer setState:STKAudioPlayerStateStopped];
                [self.mainAudioPlayer stop];
                self.playMainAudioFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:PlayIconMain];
            }
            else
            {
            [self.audioPlayer setState:STKAudioPlayerStateStopped];
            [self.audioPlayer stop];

            if(self.comments.count > 0)
            {
                UITableView *tableView = self.tabelView;
                RCommentsModel *newsStop = (self.comments)[self.indexpathForStop.row];
                newsStop.commentPlayIcon = PlayIconMain;
                [self.comments replaceObjectAtIndex:self.indexpathForStop.row withObject:newsStop];

                [tableView beginUpdates];
                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.indexpathForStop] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [tableView endUpdates];
            }
            }
        }
        else if (stopReason == STKAudioPlayerStopReasonUserAction)
        {
            if(self.isMainAudioPlay)
            {
                [self.mainAudioPlayer setState:STKAudioPlayerStateStopped];
                [self.mainAudioPlayer stop];
                self.playMainAudioFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:PlayIconMain];
            }
            else
            {
            [self.audioPlayer setState:STKAudioPlayerStateStopped];
            [self.audioPlayer stop];

            if(self.comments.count > 0)
            {
                UITableView *tableView = self.tabelView;

                RCommentsModel *newsStop = (self.comments)[self.indexpathForStop.row];
                newsStop.commentPlayIcon = PlayIconMain;
                [self.comments replaceObjectAtIndex:self.indexpathForStop.row withObject:newsStop];

                [tableView beginUpdates];
                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.indexpathForStop] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [tableView endUpdates];
            }
            }
        }
        else if (stopReason == STKAudioPlayerStopReasonNone)
        {

        }
}
```

**Hope it helps!:) I spend a lot of time to fixed it - and its worked!**